# Error was unhandled by user code un(shallow)copyable object of type <type 'Element'>, using Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I have the following code, by which I try to retrieve some F1 pilots name and url and write them into a file txt. The point is that I always get the above error. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Python 64-bit 2.7 as environment (the default was Python 34)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

#print("Hello world!")
html = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.f1-fansite.com/f1-teams/"), 'html5lib')
html.prettify()
html_teams = html.findAll("tbody")[0]
teams = []

for team in html_teams.findAll("a"):
    teams.append((team.text, team['href']))

file_teams = open("txt/teams.txt", "w")
for team in teams:
    file_teams.write(team[0] + "|" + team[1] + "\n")
file_teams.close()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, it loads and parses the site just fine here with the given source code. Also can you please give the full traceback instead of just the last line of it? Sidenote: BeautifulSoup has started to offer PEP8 compatible names with version 4, so please use those (`find_all()` instead of `findAll()`) and if you just want the first don't search for all but just use `find()`.